# How to use the values from a child class in parent class? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem that is frustrating me to no end, I have a overrideable function in a parent class, and the override function in the child class, like below:

sub class

```
Public Overrides Sub UpdatePrice(ByVal dblRetailPrice As Double)
    If dblWholesalePrice < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error, amount must be greater than 0.")
    Else
        dblRetailPrice = dblWholesalePrice * dblStandardMargin
    End If
End Sub
```

and in the parent class, i have

```
Public ReadOnly Property RetailPrice() As Double
    Get
        Return dblRetailPrice
    End Get
End Property

Public Overridable Sub UpdatePrice(ByVal dblRetailPrice As Double)
    If dblWholesalePrice < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please input an amount greater than 0,wholesale price has not changed", "error")
    Else
        dblRetailPrice = 1.1 * dblWholesalePrice
    End If
End Sub
```

When i debug, the value is produced, but it doesn't carry over to the parent class of ski.RetailPrice() , what seems to be the problem here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -0.25 for still using Hungarian notation  :P

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be passing in a parameter with the same name as a class-level variable at a higher scope. The local variable will override the other, meaning that this statement in your setter:

```
dblRetailPrice = 1.1 * dblWholesalePrice
```

will set the value of the `dblRetailPrice` temporary parameter that you just passed in, not your class-level `dblWholesalePrice` member variable.

The simple solution is to change the name of the parameter by dropping the useless type notation prefix:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Protected dblRetailPrice As Double

    Public ReadOnly Property RetailPrice() As Double
        Get
           Return dblRetailPrice
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable Sub UpdatePrice(ByVal retailPrice As Double)

       If dblWholesalePrice < 0 Then
           MessageBox.Show("Please input an amount greater than 0,wholesale price has not changed", "error")
       Else
           dblRetailPrice = 1.1 * dblWholesalePrice
       End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It would be even better to eliminate the type-prefixes altogether, everywhere.  Also, consider that the `Private` member will not be accessible in the sub class when the method is overridden.  The member will need to be `Protected`.

Comment: @TLS: Yes, it would. But it's not critical. That's merely a stylistic choice. Since VB.NET is case-insensitive, my typical strategy of naming fields with pascalCase fails, and I tend to resort to appending an equally ugly `m_` to the beginning. I was just trying not to over-complicate things here. And yes, good point about `Protected`; that was my mistake.

Comment: It's definitely a stylistic choice, as my team's preference is to use "_" as the prefix to all `Private` members.  Of course, in this case, we're talking about `Protected`.  Either way, good for a +1 in my book.

Comment: @TLS:  thanks for your help. dropping the prefixes helped, and it did pass the value now.